# How can I filter a pandas database and create a map plot based on that filtered dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, plotly

Here is the prompt I was given for this assignment:

Import the data “chicago gun violence reports.csv” from canvas into a colab notebook.  The
data contains reports of batteries in Chicago involving a gun from 2016 to 2021.
Calculate the total number of events in each police “Beat” in the data.  Which beat has the most events and how many does it contain?

Recall that John Snow used mapping to analyze clustering of cholera cases in London, and in our previous reading that was compared to gun violence in Chicago.  Here we will take a similar approach.  Create a "hotspot map" of the top 10% of beats with the most reported
batteries involving a gun. Place a circle marker at the center of each beat (as defined by the average or median of the incident locations in the beat) and make the size of the marker proportional to the number of incidents.

I am able to filter the dataset down to the top 10% of beats with the most reported events, however, I cannot put this back into a dataframe to be turned into a map plot.

Here is my code so far:

```
`from pandas.core.groupby import groupby
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
beats_path = '/content/drive/My Drive/chicago_gun_violence_reports.csv'
beats = pd.read_csv(beats_path)
# Check the loaded data
print(beats.head())
beats = pd.read_csv(beats_path)
#new events
beat_event_counts = beats['Beat'].value_counts().reset_index()
beat_event_counts.columns = ['Beat', 'Event Count']
#find most beats, number of beats
beat_with_most_events = beat_event_counts.iloc[0]['Beat']
most_events_count = beat_event_counts.iloc[0]['Event Count']
print(f"Beat {beat_with_most_events} has the most events at {most_events_count}")
# Find the 90th percentile threshold
sorted_beats = beats.sort_values(by='Beat', ascending=False)
top_10_percent_threshold = sorted_beats['Beat'].quantile(0.9)
# Filter the top 10% of beats
top_10_percent_beats = beat_event_counts[beat_event_counts['Event Count'] >= top_10_percent_threshold]
print(top_10_percent_beats)
#find centers
beat_centers = beats.groupby('Beat').agg({'Latitude': 'median', 'Longitude': 'median'}).reset_index()
    #create plot
    fig = px.scatter_mapbox(
    top_10_percent_beats,
    lat=beat_centers['Latitude'],
    lon=beat_centers['Longitude'],
    size='Event Count',
    hover_name='Beat',
)
fig.show()`
```

However, with this code, top_10_percent_beats is still an empty dataframe and I cannot figure out how to get it to work properly.

Comment: We do not have the data to reproduce your situation. If possible, would you be willing to add data or a link to which we can refer? As it is, I can't isolate whether this is a data issue or a Plotly issue.

Comment: importing groupby from pandas.core ?? Some assignments never get old, but their codes do.

Comment: Anyways, welcome to SO. Quick reading for you please: [ask] and [mre]. Editing your question so as to include the output of `print(beats.head().to_dict())`should do. It is susprising that you do have prints, but so far shared none with us. Have you done the work of isolating parts of your script to narrow down where the issue comes from? For assignments, we are advised to guide you rather than tell you the solution. Let's start with this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/12846804)

Answer (score 0):

I found a dataset that is similar to yours [here](https://data.cityofchicago.org/Public-Safety/Gun-Crimes-Heat-Map/iinq-m3rg).

Using that dataset, I don't get an empty dataframe for `top_10_percent_beats`, but there is a potential issue where `top_10_percent_beats` and `beat_centers` aren't the same length. You can join both dataframes together on the `Beat` column before passing the unified dataframe to `px.scatter_mapbox`:

```
top_10_percent_beats_centers = top_10_percent_beats.set_index('Beat').join(
    beat_centers.set_index('Beat'), how='left'
).reset_index()

#create plot
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(
    top_10_percent_beats_centers,
    lat='Latitude',
    lon='Longitude',
    size='Event Count',
    hover_name='Beat',
    mapbox_style='open-street-map'
)
fig.show()
```

[image]